# In a $p$-adic vector space, closest point on (and distance from) a plane to a given point?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\| x \| =\sqrt{x^T x}$ be the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
Consider the point $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and the plane $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : a^T x = b\}$ where $0 \neq a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Orthogonal projection gives the point 
\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
y = z - \frac{(a^T z - b)}{a^T a}  a
\end{align}
such that 
\begin{align}\label{2}\tag{2}
y \in P \qquad \text{and} \qquad \inf_{x \in P} \|x-z \| = \|y-z \|.
\end{align}
Moreover, 
\begin{align}\label{3}\tag{3}
\inf_{x \in P} \|x-z \| = \frac{| a^T z - b |}{\|a\|}
\end{align}

Suppose we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and the norm is now $\| x \| =\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|x_i|_p$.

**Question 1** How can I find a formula like \eqref{1} for some point $y \in \mathbb{Q}_p^n$ satisfying \eqref{2}.

**Question 2** How can I find a formula like \eqref{3}?

Comment: A good question, and/but there will certainly not be a unique such point (as is already the case in archimedean Banach spaces)... so it is (therefore!) harder to produce a conceptual formula for it. Not that it's necessarily impossible, or even "hard", but definitely "harder" due to non-uniqueness.

Comment: @paulgarrett It didn't think the point would be unique. But you make a good point about it being harder to find a formula because of non-uniqueness.

Comment: @paulgarrett I added a second question, which should be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comment by @user1952009 on ["Reciprocal" of $p$-adic vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355577/reciprocal-of-p-adic-vector?noredirect=1&lq=1), I've got an answer for **Question 2**: 
$$
\inf_{x \in P} \|x-z\|_p = \frac{|a^T z - b|_p}{\|a\|_p}
$$

We prove the equality as two inequalities.

For the $\leq$ part, pick $j$ such that $\|a\|_p = |a_{j}|_p$ and let $x = z - (a^T z - b)(0,\ldots,0,a_{j}^{-1},0,\ldots,0)$. Then we find $|x-z|_p = \|a\|_p^{-1} |a^T z - b|_p$ and $a^Tx = b$.

For the $\geq$ part, for all $x$ with $a^Tx=b$, we have 
$$
|a^T z - b|_p = |a^T z - a^T x|_p = | \sum_{i} a_i(z_{i} - x_{i})  |_p \leq \max_{i} |a_i(z_{i} - x_{i})|_p \leq \|a\|_p \|x-z\|_p.
$$

Edit: I guess this also answers **Question 1**: $y$ may be taken to be the point $x$ constructed in the first part of the proof.