# "Reciprocal" of $p$-adic vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

For $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p^n$, $\|x\|_p = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i|_p$ where $|  \cdot |_p$ is the $p$-adic absolute value.

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $a \neq 0$. How can we find $a' \in \mathbb{Q}_p^n$ such that 
$$
a^T a' = \sum_{i} a_i a_i' = 1 \quad \text{ and } \quad 
\|a\|_p \|a'\|_p \leq 1?
$$

If $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}$ and $\| \cdot \|_p$ is replaced by the Euclidean norm, we could take $a' = \dfrac{1}{a^T a} a$.

This question came up in thinking about this question: [In a $p$-adic vector space, closest point on a plane to a given point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355342/in-a-p-adic-vector-space-closest-point-on-a-plane-to-a-given-point)

Comment: $\|a\|_p = |a_i|_p$ let $a' = (0,\ldots, a_i^{-1}, 0, \ldots)$

Comment: @user1952009 So obvious! Thanks.